# RegEx to Match Phrase with Spaces

Tags: regex

I have a line similar to the following:

```
DESCRIPTION RIGHT HERE   EA  005   1            1      0000001     04/05/16              008
```

I am trying to extract the phrase `DESCRIPTION RIGHT HERE`.  The description is different each time so I will not know the length of it from line to line.  However, there is always more than one space after the description phrase.

What regex do I need to use in order to obtain the description phrase from the line?

Comment: Split with " EA ".

Comment: like this :- https://regex101.com/r/sD1lB7/2

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this I guess.
Description to Description or end of string.
Answer in capture group 1.

`DESCRIPTION RIGHT HERE\s(.*?)(?=DESCRIPTION RIGHT HERE|$)`

Answer (score 0):

`^([^$]*?)\s\s` should lazy match everything followed by two spaces, which means you are going to get just the description in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
^(.*?)(?=\s{2})
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gJ1bC5/1)